# How to make a Generic average method, so that you can put any type in it?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I Try to make a Generic average method. So that the method can interact with any type. But also the values of the any type has to be generic. so that you can have types of: int, float, decimal.

I try it with like this:

```
public class Calculator<T>
    {
        public T Average(List<T>items, Func<T, T>  getValue )
        {

            T sum = 0 ;

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                sum += getValue(item);
            }

            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(sum / items.Count(), typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a example class like this:

```
public  class Product<T>
    {

        public T Weight { get; set; }

    }
```

But I already get an error on this line:

```
   T sum = 0 ;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'

and the Program class:

```
            var listProducts = new List<Product<int>> { 
                    new Product<int>{ Weight = 1},
                    new Product<int> { Weight = 2},
                    new Product<int> { Weight = 87}
            };
            var calc2 = new Calculator<Product<int>>();
            var averageWeight = calc2.Average(listProducts, p => p.Weight);

            Console.WriteLine($"Average weight is: {averageWeight}" );
```

I have it now like this:

```
public class Calculator<T> where T: class
    {
        public T Average(List<T>items, Func<T, T>  getValue )
        {

            T sum = default(T);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                sum += getValue(item);
            }

            return (sum / items.Count());
        }
    }
```

But I get this errror:

```
'+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

ON this line:

```
sum += getValue(item);
```

Comment: Please, have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare the default value per follows

```cs
T sum = default(T);
```

It also makes sense to use the generic type constraint for calculation, if you are using only numeric value types

```cs
where S : struct, IComparable, IComparable<S>, IConvertible, IEquatable<S>, IFormattable
```

Also, you've passed `p => p.Weight` as `Func<T, T> getValue`, which is incorrect, you should declare additional generic type parameter for return value in `Func<T, TResult>`, currently you accept and return the same type

Finally, I make your snippet working, by adding an additional generic parameter and making `sum` as `dynamic` to avoid compile time errors

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listProducts = new List<Product<int>> {
            new Product<int> { Weight = 1},
            new Product<int> { Weight = 2},
            new Product<int> { Weight = 87}
        };
        var calc2 = new Calculator<Product<int>, int>();
        var averageWeight = calc2.Average(listProducts, p => p.Weight);

        Console.WriteLine($"Average weight is: {averageWeight}");
    }
}

public class Calculator<T, S> where S : struct, IComparable, IComparable<S>, IConvertible, IEquatable<S>, IFormattable
{
    public S Average(List<T> items, Func<T, S> getValue)
    {
        dynamic sum = default(S);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var result = getValue(item);
            sum += result;
        }

        return (S)Convert.ChangeType(sum / items.Count, typeof(S));
    }
}
```

It prints

> Average weight is: 30

In your snippet `Product<int>` as generic type parameter for `Calculator` and `int` is generic type parameter for `Product<T>`, you can't use both of them as one parameter in `getValue` and return back from `Average`

Comment: Ah, thank you. Very nice. But why are you using struct? And not class?

Comment: Ah, oke, of course, becuase decimal is a value type, like  a struct. And class is by reference. Isn't it?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Yes, you are right, because for non value types you can get an exception, when try to sum or divide. Of course, you can override these operators, but this is an additional topic:)